# Scanner.hasNext() not working properly when running in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I wrote a simple program to loop and find max of a set of numbers input by the user as:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int currMax, currEl;
  currMax = sc.nextInt();

  while (sc.hasNext()) {
    currEl = sc.nextInt();
    currMax = (currEl > currMax ? currEl : currMax);
  }
  sc.close();
  System.out.println(currMax);
} // end function main

}
```

---

I am using Eclipse on Windows.

When I run it the first time it runs fine, and considers Ctrl-Z as EOF and exits the loop. But second time onwards, it does not seem to read the EOF. I am unable to explain this, or fix this behavior.. what do you think is going on, and how do I fix it??

---

**Follow-up:** The problem happens with Eclipse, and not when I use cmd line. I suspect this is what is happening -- if I use cmd line, I can do Ctrl-Z and then hit Enter, but if I use Eclipse, I believe as soon as I hit Ctrl-Z, s.hasNext() evaluates to false and the above program terminates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while (scanner.hasNext()) loop not working twice? Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228558/while-scanner-hasnext-loop-not-working-twice-java)

Comment: I see the same behavior under Eclipse Mars for Windows. There was an Eclipse  bug in this area some years back, perhaps it was not fully fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=34052